# How to separate cumulative bars and graph in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to turn this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

How I can do this?

(!!!) That is, raise the graph and normalize it and the columns so that the spread is not so large
I tried to expand the A range to get the second chart, but it didn't turn out pretty. Are there any built-in functions?

Comment: You will need to provide more details then this. I suspect it will be matter of adjusting the Y-axis and/or the Secondary y-axis ranges.